# What is the opt in the __asm grammar and how can semi-colons be used as comments without autoformatting?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, visual-c++, grammar, inline-assembly

What is the meaning of `opt` in the grammar for invoking the inline assembler with `__asm` keyword?  Is it trying to say the ending semi-colons are optional?

Semi-colons are usually used as comments in assembly.  I find when I'm not using any semi-colons in my `assembly-instruction-list`, after typing one for a comment Visual Studio will do very strange autoformatting of the assembly instructions that I cannot seem to disable or make sense of.

```
Grammar
asm-block:
    __asm assembly-instruction ;opt
    __asm { assembly-instruction-list } ;opt

assembly-instruction-list:
    assembly-instruction ;opt
    assembly-instruction ; assembly-instruction-list ;opt
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/asm

Comment: Yes, the subscript "opt" indicates the preceding symbol is optional. Refer to Section 4.3 of [the latest draft of the ISO C++ Spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/n4901.pdf) for a description of the syntax of the restricted EBNF.

Comment: MSVC asm block syntax is like MASM (same for `clang -fasm-blocks` or `clang-cl`); semi-colons are just a comment character, and are optional.  https://godbolt.org/z/ETYvEEhfP shows that it's definitely fine in practice, regardless of whether Visual Studio's editor makes a mess of it.